# Printing row names for values in a matrix

Tags: r

Im having problems printing the rowname for specific values within a matrix.  The following two questions have been difficult.

1. On which day(s) did she arrive the fastest in the first week? (Only the day(s) of the week should print. (Hint: Use the row names.)
2. Determine the day(s) of the second week on which she arrived to work within a half an hour. (Only the day(s) of the week should print.)

This is the data set called commutes

```
          Week1 Week2
Monday       26    22
Tuesday      35    23
Wednesday    24    36
Thursday     31    32
Friday       34    25
```

Comment: for question one `names(which.min(s[,1]))` and `names(which(s[,2]<30))` for the second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use the [`which()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/which) function to find the index of the smallest value in the first column. You provide `which()` with a logical object (in this case, a vectorized equal test). Supposing you have your matrix bound to `m`:

```
ind = which(m[,'Week1'] == min(m[,'Week1']))
```

You can then take the use the index to get the row name matching that logical using [`rownames()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.2/topics/row%2Bcolnames):

```
day = rownames(m)[ind]
```

2) This is essentially the same thing, except you will be expecting a vector of indices rather than a single index. Again use `which()` to find the indices which match the desired logical expression:

```
inds = which(m$Week2 < 30)
days = rownames(m)[inds]
```